# Backbone Node - fetch - server sending only response object but not model ,how can i get model?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

Backbone,Node : when i call fetch method,  fetch is successful in server but when it sends response back using

```
res.send(result)
```

it is not sending(may be) any model or it is sending old model back,and it is sending only response object . Model is what i want, how can i get ?

```
app.get('/college/colleges/:_id', function (req, res) {

    oid = new ObjectID(req.params._id.toString());
    return CollegeModel.find({
        _id: oid
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Fetched college model successfully");
            res.send(result);
        } else {

            console.log("Error : " + err);
            res.send(err);

        }
    });
});
```

the above code is in node . Below one is in client javascript (in a view).

```
college_model = new CollegeModel(id)
college_model.fetch({
    success = function (model, res, options) {
        console.log model // here , new model should come with all new attributes, but old model with only id attribute is appearing here,,,in model format.
        console.log res // here, i am getting all required records in objectformat,no problem for this res
    }
    error = function (model, res, options) {
        console.log("Error ");
    }

})
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer

instead of sending

```
         res.send(result);
```

send like  this :

```
         res.send(result[0]);
```

then the result will be fine !